# Azure Function App access to on-prem resource (Gateway?)

Tags: c#, azure, azure-function-app-proxy

I have a requirement to use an Azure Function App to query data in an on-premise SQL database, extract that data, dump it to a blob.

By these requirements ADF is not permissible.

The on premise SQL engine is behind a firewall.

How does Azure/the FunctionApp gain a connection to the SQL Engine to run the required select queries?

Answer (score 2):

For Azure AppService, you can use [Hybrid Connections](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/app-service-hybrid-connections) to access a private network from within your AppService. This can be your route into the on premise network.

The same is possible for Function Apps, as long as you use an app service plan with level "standard" or higher. Consumption plan is not supported. You can find it under "Platform features - Networking"

A full step-by-step tutorial can be found here: [How to Azure Function App with Hybrid Connection](https://www.thebestcsharpprogrammerintheworld.com/2018/08/21/how-to-azure-function-app-with-hybrid-connection/).

[Here is also a video about the idea.](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/resources/videos/azure-app-service-with-hybrid-connections-to-on-premises-resources/)